# pass data from one gridview to another gridview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, row

I am using two grid view in the different form, I want to pass the form1 all cells values
another Form[form2]. form2 data ***view in one cell***. then click the form2 cell load the all data view in form1 cells.

this form1 ->

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] colB = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++)
        {
            colB[i] = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

        }
    }
```

how to get data form2->
?

Comment: we cant write code from scratch, show us what you have so far.

Comment: Usually to represent complex data, it is recommended to work with a model class, so the information is decoupled from the View (the Grid). If you code was to be organized this way, you could simply pass the reference of the model object between the two Windows. If you work in WPF, look for the MVVM pattern. If you work with Windows Forms, look for the MVP (MVC) pattern.

Comment: I would suggest to create new static class and assign value to that class and access that class from form2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms are classes like any other. However, they have window-specific behaviors they inherit from the `Form` class.

This means you can specify your own constructor and pass along any information you would like. For instance, let's say we have a Person class we want to show in a new Form. We could define a new `PersonForm` to show the details (this is just an example. You will be able to adapt it to your needs).

```
public class PersonForm : Form 
{
    PersonForm(Person model)
    {
        InitializeComponents(); //I think this is the name of the method.

        //Do whatever is needed here with the model.
    }
}
```

So when a user double clicks the right cell, you create a new instance of the `PersonForm` and you show it.